# How to disable the play pause button in AVPlayerViewController on tvOS?

Tags: objective-c, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I have a live video in my AVPlayerViewController and i want to disable the play pause button. How can I do that?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *playPauseRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];  
playPauseRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypePlayPause)];
[self.avPlayerViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:playPauseRec ];
```

The AVPlayerViewController is a child view controller of a View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable all events (play/pause/seek) you can do this by setting the `isUserInteractionEnabled` flag of your `AVPlayerViewController` to `false`.

```
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    // ... setup playerViewController here

    // disable userinteraction - so no play/pause/seek events are triggered anymore
    playerViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Call a different method on action of that button. I have done that by calling nothing on Action of Gesture. Here is my code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(PlayPause)];
tapGestureRec.allowedPressTypes = @[@(UIPressTypePlayPause)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRec];
```

and in playPause Function

```
-(void)PlayPause
  {
 NSLog(@"Do Anything or Nothing");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use private APIs and want a little bit more control you can set a private delegate on AVPlayerViewController. The delegate provides some special callbacks which among other things allow you to disable pause completely.

```
@objc protocol YourPrivateAVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
  @objc optional func playerViewController(_ controller: AVPlayerViewController, shouldPlayFromTime: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
  @objc optional func playerViewController(_ controller: AVPlayerViewController, shouldPauseWithCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
}
```

You could implement the second delegate method and call shouldPauseWithCompletion(false) to disable pause. If you want to disable pause depending on the type of stream or some other properties you could do that as well of course.

Set the delegate implementation on the AVPlayerViewController with:

```
playerController.perform(Selector(("setPrivateDelegate:")), with: self)
```